# Buffalo airstation WCR-GN stuck on diag

Tags: networking, router, lan, wireless-access-point

The diag LED is supposed to go off after a minute or so after boot, but it doesn't. The entire device is unaccessible. It happens when I boot it with nothing plugged in, and also when the WAN is connected to the main router (the buffalo is supposed to bridge) and it also happens when I connect it from LAN1-4 to laptop or PC.

So no matter how I connect, it never stops DIAG.

The reset button seems unresponsive too. I tried pressing it for 3sec, 10sec, right after boot and before boot. Doesn't do a thing ;(

Any ideas?

Comment: Hold the reset button in while you power it up, release 3 seconds after powerup light comes on. It might be a dead Buffalo.

Comment: Didn't do the trick I'm afraid, it didn't reset to factory default :( After rebooting it with the WAN connected to the router, I managed to get online wtih it for a minute or so though, after which it became unresponsive again. Is it safe to assume the thing is simply broken?

Comment: Malware infection on the PC is the only other possibility that comes to mind.

Comment: Nah I keep it clean. Mainly by not using social media, which I believe is responsible for 90% of all infected computers worldwide LOL. Plus it's happening on all computers I try to connect with. I guess I'll opt in for a warranty replacement, thanks.

Comment: See if there is a firmware update for the airstation and apply it.